# Getting samples out of a given distribution

Tags: distributions

I get an error in mathematica when i try to get 10 samples of a MultinormalDistribution with:

```
sample = 10;
cov = {{0.0000606844, -0.000132364, -0.000149518}, {-0.000132364, 0.00103449,
   0.000833935}, {-0.000149518, 0.000833935, 0.00071455}};
mu= {0.00355655, -0.0517223, -0.026937};
dist = MultinormalDistribution[mu, cov]
```

Now by applying RandomVariate with a TruncatedDistribution between -1, 1 i want to generate 10 samples:

```
RandomVariate[
  TruncatedDistribution[
   ConstantArray[{-1, 1}, Length@mu], dist],
   sample] // Transpose
```

Instead i get the error Message

```
"The first argument of \
TruncatedDistribution[{{-1,1},{-1,1},{-1,1}},MultinormalDistribution[{\
0.00355655,-0.0517223,-0.026937},{{0.0000606844,-0.000132364,-0.\
000149518},<<1>>,{<<1>>}}]] is expected to be a valid truncation \
specification for the distribution \
MultinormalDistribution[{0.00355655,-0.0517223,-0.026937},<<1>>]."
```

Anyone knows what im doing wrong?

Comment: In the definition of "cov" is a brace missing.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out, ive corrected the typo

Comment: So everything seems to work now but I think you probably want to remove the `//Transpose`.

Comment: Similar to [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/257360/drawing-samples-from-mulitnormaldistribution/257361#257361)

Answer (score 2):

I think the only problem is the in your Cover definition you are missing an opening brace for the two-dimensional list.  When I fix that, it all runs fine.

```
cov = {{0.0000606844, -0.000132364, -0.000149518}, {-0.000132364, 
    0.00103449, 0.000833935}, {-0.000149518, 0.000833935, 0.00071455}};
```

Comment: Can you also try if it works for cov = {{0.000060684445410704884, -0.00013236382921520424, 
-0.00014951795735534325},
 {-0.00013236382921519838, 0.0010344930628389817, 
  0.0008339346647649739},
 {-0.00014951795735533924, 0.0008339346647649794, 
  0.0007145497794991608}} because for me it doesn't

Comment: Seems fine.  result = {{0.00473948, -0.00541791, -0.0117304, 
  0.0012606, -0.00244112, -0.0131913, -0.00249456, -0.00812925, 
  0.00261845, -0.00296656}, {-0.0771857, -0.042381, -0.0869528, \
-0.0700794, 0.000998352, -0.0252476, -0.0346295, -0.0281032, 
  0.0125222, -0.0793516}, {-0.0461421, -0.0124056, -0.0348435, \
-0.0370063, 0.0168411, 0.00709373, -0.0101654, 0.000862649, 
  0.0173782, -0.0391015}}

Comment: Hmm i still get the same error as explained in the beginning. This is really strange behaviour. I use Mathematica 12.0